# how to reject from an AR association where a specific condition exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to remove items from the following association (where a site_placement has a native_ad_placement.ad_type == "video") and have the following code but this doesn't seem to work

```
# not an array but an association
@sites.each do |site|
  site.site_placements.reject { |sp| (sp.native_ad_placement.ad_type == "video") }
end
```

How could I achieve this? I'm using Rails 3.2.

Comment: `site.site_placements.map { |sp| (sp.native_ad_placement.ad_type != "video") }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.reject!` instead of `.reject`.

But really, you shouldn't use reject at all. If I am not wrong, you can totally achieve the same thing at querying level, and it is even much more effective. Something like below:

```
Site.includes(site_placements: [: native_ad_placement]).where.not(native_ad_placements: { ad_type: "video" })
```

Comment: I think `where.not` wasn't introduced until Rails 4 and he's on 3.2. I'm not sure if it was backported? Either way, this is still a solid recommendation. he may just need to build part of the query by hand

Comment: thx - y - `reject!` works. would normally do this via query but have to work with results directly in this case for legacy code reasons.